# ArcGIS Pro Layers - Update Data Sources with Model Builder & ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, layers

So I'm attempting to write a script that updates the data source for the layers in my map. The script is incorporated into a model and gets some of the pathways from the model's outputs. When I run the script it does update the first group layer in the map, but I need it to update all the layers in the map (if it can do it across multiple maps in the project that would be ideal). I was reading here; https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/updatingandfixingdatasources.htm but I'm assuming I'm missing some element that is able to cycle through layers or something along those lines. As my python experience started around last week I'm a bit unsure how to go about that. My code is below.

```
import arcpy
import os
    #Select current project
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
    #identify project folder and updated GDB names from parameters, these parameters will be generated within the model
folder = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
activeGDB = arcpy.GetParameter(1)
backGDB = arcpy.GetParameter(2)
    #create path variables by joining the project folder pathway with the names of the generic and renamed GDB's
activePath = os.path.join(folder, "active.gdb") 
activePathNew = os.path.join(folder, activeGDB)
backPath = os.path.join(folder, "background.gdb")
backPathNew = os.path.join(folder, backGDB)
    #Update the data connections
aprx.updateConnectionProperties(activePath, activePathNew) 
aprx.updateConnectionProperties(backPath, backPathNew)
    #Save
aprx.save()
```

Comment: Are you running this script within a Calculate Value tool within your model?

Comment: The script does exist within a model, there's no Calculate Value tool involved however, the model is intended to output the pathways for the current gdb locations using the Parse Path tool.

Comment: I think you need to provide more evidence. A screen shot of your TOC would help. You say it updates first group layer in the map, so these second/third group layers may be they have data in an entirely different workspace? You need to show what it is you really have for anyone to suggest a  solution. Amend you question.